# Split url string in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, url, split

I am trying to split a url string in Python 3.

The code is like this.

```
url = 'https://www.jstage.jst.go.jp/browse/mesj/58/1-2/_contents/-char/en'

url = url.replace('https://www.jstage.jst.go.jp/browse/', '')

j, v, n, _ = url.split('/')

print(j, v, n)
```

I want to extract journal name, volume and number from a url.

But there is an error like this.

```
user@users-MacBook-Pro-5 ~ % /usr/bin/python3 /Users/user/Downloads/test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/Downloads/test.py", line 5, in <module>
    j, v, n, _ = url.split('/')
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 4)
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: There are 6 pieces in that split path, which you're trying to assign to only 4 variables…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because url (mesj/58/1-2/_contents/-char/en) has five '/', you should use `j, v, n, _, __ = url.split('/')`.

But, the following code is more useful.

```
j, v, n, *_ = url.split('/')
```

The first, second, third one are assigned to j, v, n, and the others are assigned to _.

Comment: or `j, v, n = url.split('/')[0:3]`